# Reference for cores and quotients of partitions

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, integer-partitions

I wanned to ask you guys for some nice references concerning the combinatoric of core and quotients of partitions of integers.
Thanks in advance for your responses,
Best
Rhylx

Comment: Here is [a set of notes by Jørn Olsson](http://web.math.ku.dk/~olsson/manus/comb_rep_all.pdf).

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot :). I couldn't find any book speaking about that, do you agree?